# How to compare dictionaries when the case of the value does not matter?

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries `d1` and `d2`:

```
>>> d1 = {'name':'John Smith', 'age':36}
>>> d2 = {'name':'john smith', 'age':36}
```

I want to make sure, that two dictionaries are identical, but I don't care about the `name` value case. In addition, I need to avoid modifying the dictionaries.

I could solve it by copying directories like this:

```
>>> d1_lc = d1.copy()
>>> d2_lc = d2.copy()
>>>
>>> d1_lc['name'] = d1['name'].casefold()
>>> d2_lc['name'] = d2['name'].casefold()
>>>
>>> if d1_lc == d2_lc:
...     do_something_with_d1(d1)
...
```

Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Possibly make a throwaway value and set it to uppercase for comparison

Comment: Alt: Convert them to classes and implement `__eq__`

Comment: @drum can't upvote, but a very pythonic solution imo.

Comment: `all(v == d2[k] if k != 'name' else v.casefold() == d2[k].casefold() for k, v in d1.items())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generator expression to check each value:

```
all(d1[k] == d2[k] if k != "name" else d1[k].lower() == d2[k].lower() for k in d1)
# True
```

You can also add `set(d1.keys()) == set(d2.keys())` if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following:

```py
d1 = {'name':'John Smith', 'age':36}
d2 = {'name':'john smith', 'age':36}

def regularize(d):
    return {k: (v.casefold() if isinstance(v, str) else v) for k, v in d.items()}

if regularize(d1) == regularize(d2):
    print('hello!')
```

This converts only the string values into lower case.

Update: If only the key `'name'` needs to be casefolded, then:

```py
d1 = {'name':'John Smith', 'age':36}
d2 = {'name':'john smith', 'age':36}

def regularize(d):
    return {k: (v.casefold() if k == 'name' else v) for k, v in d.items()}

if regularize(d1) == regularize(d2):
    print('hello!')
```

Comment: Nice, but was mentioned he only needs to do case-insensitive match against `name` key. I'm not sure if it means matching other keys would (not?) be case-insensitive.

Comment: Not nice that both dicts must copied before comparing them.

Comment: @ekhumoro I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) which I personally prefer.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import cached_property


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Compare with a case-insensitive match on the `name` field."""
        if not isinstance(other, Person):
            return False

        return self.name_to_compare == other.name_to_compare

    @cached_property
    def name_to_compare(self):
        return self.name.casefold()
```

Code for testing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    d1 = {'name': 'John Smith', 'age': 36}
    d2 = {'name': 'john smith', 'age': 36}

    p1 = Person(**d1)
    p2 = Person(**d2)

    if p1 == p2:
        print('Hooray!')
        # access rest of attributes on class object instead of dict
        # print('Person 1 name:', p1.name)
```